# How to match a list item using XQuery <intValues>1 2 3</intValues>

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to match against ids stored as [list](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_list.asp) element using XQuery.

For example,

```
<data>
    <item>
        <name>foo</name>
        <intValues>1 2 3 4 5</intValues>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>bar</name>
        <intValues>6 7 8 9 10</intValues>
    </item>
</data>
```

is it possible to return items that include 3 in the `intValues`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to return items that
>   include 3 in the intValues?

**This XPath expression** *selects exactly all `item` elements that have a '3' as one of the list of values contained in their* `intValues` *child*:

**`/*/item['3' = tokenize(intValues, ' ')]`**

Comment: @Dimitre sorry have to put this here in SQL we have `WHERE Column IN (LIST_OF_Values)` what is the equivalent XQuery ? i know this `Column.exist('/users/user[@Id=sql:variable(blah_blah_blah)]')` instead of checking only one variable i need to match it with list of all values. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons: What prevents you from *asking a SO question*? This is an XML, XQuery tag -- you need to show us an XML document and ask how specific nodes in it can be selected, or other information extracted/calculated. This is equivalent to providing a table type (the set of column definitions) for a SQL question.

Answer (score 2):

If your xml file has a schema and you are using a schema-aware processor then the query is just

```
/data/item[intValues = 3]
```

otherwise, as Dimitre suggests you will have to tokenize this manually.